# How to serialize a self recursive many-to-many model using a through table in django rest_framework?

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

i am developing a rest API using django rest framework and i am stuck at a serializer the idea is to serialize a self recursive many to many model using a through table my code is:

model.py:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'patients'

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    id_card = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    dob = models.DateField()
    gender = EnumChoiceField(enum_class=Gender)
    patientscol = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    fk_user = models.ForeignKey(Users, related_name='user_patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    relative = models.ManyToManyField("self", through='PatientHasRelative')

class PatientHasRelative(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'patients_has_relatives'

    fk_patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, related_name='patient_has', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fk_relative_patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, related_name='patient_relative', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    relationship = EnumChoiceField(enum_class=Relationship)
```

my serializer.py is:

```
class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ('__all__')

    id = serializers.UUIDField(read_only=True)
    id_card = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=45)
    dob = serializers.DateField(required=True)
    gender = EnumChoiceField(enum_class=Gender)
    fk_user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=True, queryset=Users.objects.all())
    relative = PatientSerializer(read_only=True, required=True)#problem is here i cant use PatientSerializer here

class PatientHasRelativeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PatientHasRelative
        fields = ('__all__')

    fk_patient = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=True, queryset=Patient.objects.all())
    fk_relative_patient = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=True, queryset=Patient.objects.all())
    relationship = EnumChoiceField(enum_class=Relationship)
```

a little help would be appreciated

Comment: Just curious, in `serializer.py`, why are you specifying each fields again ? If you are using ModelSerializer you don't need to mention all again. can you remove all the serializer fields definitions in both Serializer classes. See what happens

Comment: if i remove the fields from the serializer.py will i still be able to use .is_valid() ? to validate the data?

Comment: yes it should be, thats the magic of ModelSerializer, it inherits all the attributes of the Model and adds them to validators

Comment: thanks for the comment :)

Comment: ok i'll try it, thankx

Comment: ...but did it work?!

Comment: yep it worked sorry for the late reply :)

Comment: How did you manage this?
```relative = PatientSerializer(read_only=True, required=True)#problem is here i cant use PatientSerializer here```
Can you post the solution? cos I'm try to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this you need to define `related_name` in the source model on the source field ie add

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    relatives = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self", through='PatientHasRelative', related_name='patients')
```

with this `related_name` you can easily access -- add/delete/set relatives/patients on either side of the relationships in the serializers
You can either do this using intermediary model

```
relative = Patient(**key_value_fields)
patient = Patient(**key_value_field)

PatientHasRelative.objects.create(
 relative=relative, patient=patient, through_defaults=(relationship ='value',))
```

or you can do this

```
relative.patients.add(patient, through_defaults=relationship ='value')
```

or this

```
patient.relatives.add(relative, through_defaults=relationship ='value')
```

example retrieving

```
patient.relatives.all()
```